# Huge elementals attacks

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat, attack, multiattack

In DnD 3.5, huge elementals have a Base Attack Bonus (BAB) above 6. For example, Huge Air has +12 and Greater Air has +15. This means that they can hit above 1 time and, in particular, the greater can hit 3 times.

But, in the monster stats (Monster Manual 1, page 96) and at the Full Attack entry, there is only the

> Full Attack: 2 slams +23 melee (2d8+5)

This means that the Greater Air Elemental (which has BAB of +15) can only hit 2 times, even if it has the BAB for hitting 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No iterative attacks for natural attacks

The Slam attack is a natural attack according to the [SRD](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#natural-weapons), which also says in that section:

> Creatures do not receive additional attacks from a high base attack bonus when using natural weapons.

So, in order to have iterative attacks, the elemental would have to be wielding a [manufactured weapon](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#manufactured-weapons) or using [unarmed strikes](http://dndsrd.net/weapons.html#unarmed-strike) (which aren't listed in the [entry](http://dndsrd.net/monstersEtoF.html#elemental), and with which the elemental would have a [nonprofiency penalty](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#elemental) and garner attacks of opportunity if using the unarmed strikes).

Your reading of the entry is indeed correct: it only gets 2 slams when it performs a full attack action.

Comment: Elementals are not proficient with simple weapons, so would also take a nonproficiency penalty. Unless generally humanoid in form.

Comment: Also, the "2 slams" are one attack? Not two?

Comment: @Xxxo The slams are 2 separate attacks at the same bonus see the 'Attack' line vs the 'Full Attack Line'

Comment: @Xxxo The elemental has 2 slams because it has 2 weapons that deal slam attacks. Like a troll has 2 hands with claws and deal 2 claw attacks, one from each hand.